# Procedure to get employees average salary and increase it if it is below average

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create package and procedure where i find all employes that are working in a job that starts with MA or SA and if their salary is below average salary, then increase their salary by 33%.

I can't find the problem and make it work.

Here is the code, can't get it to work:

```
create or replace package body name2 as 
procedure one(
alga emp.sal%type,
new_sal emp.sal%type)
cursor kursors1 is
select ename, sal from emp where job LIKE 'MA%' OR e.job LIKE 'SA%' for update sal;
begin 
select round(avg(sal),2) videja_alga into alga from emp
for darb in kursors1
loop 
if darb.sal < alga then
new_sal:=darb.sal+(darb.sal*0.33);
dbms_output.put_line('New sal: ' || darb.sal);
update emp set sal = new_sal where current of kursors1;
end if;
end loop;
end;
end name2;
/
```

Comment: You really want to do pl/sql? Not an Sql statement? update emp set sal = sal*0.33 where (job like 'MA%' OR e.job LIKE 'SA%') and sal < (select avg(salary) from emp)

Answer (score 0):

Please put proper next time. Its really hard to interpret otherwise.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY name2
AS
   PROCEDURE one (alga emp.sal%TYPE, new_sal emp.sal%TYPE)
   AS
      CURSOR kursors1
      IS
         SELECT ename, sal
           FROM emp
          WHERE job LIKE 'MA%' OR e.job LIKE 'SA%';
   BEGIN
      SELECT ROUND (AVG (sal), 2) videja_alga
        INTO alga
        FROM emp;

      FOR darb IN kursors1
      LOOP
         IF darb.sal < alga
         THEN
            new_sal := darb.sal + (darb.sal * 0.33);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('New sal: ' || darb.sal);

            UPDATE emp
               SET sal = new_sal
             WHERE CURRENT OF kursors1;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
   END;
END name2;
```

Changes done:

1. Removed  for update sal from cursor. I am not sure what it does as your simply looping through it.
2. ';' was missing in avg calculation select statement
3. Added 'as' before cursor declaration as it is part of standard procedure creation.

This whole code can be done in much less, try using partition by that will give you avg value in the cursor itself and you can do the calculation in the cursor itself with just an update below which will loop through the cursor.

Comment: The for update he is using for the update clause, where he is using "where current of" . Very useful in the right situations.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.